# Filter LINQ query using items from an external list with Lambda

Tags: linq, lambda

How do you rewrite this in lambda?

```
int[] productList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var myProducts = from p in db.Products
                 where productList.Contains(p.ProductID)
                select p;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "with lambda" you mean the "query syntax", you can rewrite your query like this:

```
var myProducts = db.Products.Where(p => productList.Contains(p.ProductID));
```

Answer (score 1):

Same thing just move the logic within a `Where` call.

```
var myProducts = db.Products.Where(p => productList.Contains(p.ProductID));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx

^ a quick read that compares query syntax to method syntax for a query to two.